# R: Matrix Multiplication (Practical Graph Mining with R)

Tags: r, matrix

In the book (page 105 / 106) a matrix is multiplied with a vector:

```
# create a matrix that shows the links between pages
A = matrix(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
          0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
          0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
          nrow = 6, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE,
          dimnames = list(c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6"),
                             c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6")));

h = c(rep(1,6));
t(A) * h
```

When running this, I get a matrix out of it, not a vector. What matrix operation is the author doing and how does it map to R as the result is the sum of that resulting matrix, which is:

```
bookResult = c(1,3,5,1,2,1)
```

Best,
R

Comment: I need that book in pdf :-|

Comment: You can find some chapters here: http://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/samatova/practical-graph-mining-with-R/PracticalGraphMiningWithR.html#SampleChapters

Comment: Cool! I found the slides pdf via goodle on FSM, it's great that they have provided R packages on the site (you mentioned). I was frustrated I couldn't find packages on cran :P
Thanks!

Comment: Any success in finding the book in pdf? I found the pdf slides are pretty good but the samples from google books shown that the book is even more wonderful :) A bit expensive anyway :) @Asymptote

Comment: Nope :-| didn't find the pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For matrix multiplication in R, you should use `%*%`, not `*`. (I’m a little unclear: is the code you’ve posted something you’ve written, or an extract from the book?)

Anyway, using this operator gives the same result you want:

```
> t(A) %*% h
   [,1]
d1    1
d2    3
d3    5
d4    1
d5    2
d6    1
> as.vector(t(A) %*% h)
[1] 1 3 5 1 2 1
```

You can learn more about matrix multiplication in R by typing `?matmult` at an R prompt.

Comment: +1. I was just about to post the same thing after re-reading the question.

Comment: Its exactly from the book, its part of HITS but the operation itself i not expressed in R syntax...

Comment: So, what is the difference between * and %*% in mathematical language?

Comment: @RalfB: Mathematically, they both correspond to multiplication. The difference is that in R, `*` means component-wise multiplication (of vectors), while `%*%` tells it to treat the terms as matrices/vectors, and perform matrix multiplication.